# Radio buttons in array for edit form

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have form that has rows which send data in array. Everything works ok, only problem is with radio buttons, when I want to edit data, they are printed with checked=checked attribute, but all browsers only register last ckecked radio button. I have tried everything I can think of, not even hack with jQuery works and jQuery does the same.

```
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][0]" value="/images/Targets/target2.png">
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][0]" value="/images/Targets/target1.png" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][0]" value="/images/Targets/target3.png">

<input type="radio" name="targets[image][1]" value="/images/Targets/target2.png">
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][1]" value="/images/Targets/target1.png" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][1]" value="/images/Targets/target3.png">
```

When I submit the form, then it sends only last radio as checked. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: For handling submit there is simple PHP script that handles $_POST
I dont want to selecte multiple values for one group, but it seems that it takes all those groups as one group, its like it ignores index in array [0]

Comment: Could you add some of the JavaScript/jQuery that you have tried already? That would help us to help you.

Comment: Is name same for all of them? I mean are targets[image][0] and targets[image][1] returning same values?

Comment: Radio buttons only pass one value for the group. It looks like in your snippet above you'd get one checked radio button per group - is that what you're seeing? What technology are you working with server-side to receive this? (From what I see above, your HTML looks like it's fine)

Comment: @Tim what could he use instead?

Comment: @limelights - if he wants multiple values, he should be using checkboxes, which would pass mutliple values within the group.

Comment: @Tim in post there is value only for the second group, on server there is just PHP script to handle $_POST

Comment: always there is value only for the last group, doesnt matter how many groups there are or how many groups have one of their values selected I always get only last group

Comment: @SamHuckaby when you use $(':checked') it only detects last groups checked value too, but with $('[checked=checked]') it gets all those that are checked, but using click on them doesnt work too, dont know why

Comment: Do you have any broken HTML in your page? Sometimes a missing tag or a missing quotation mark can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution that I tried seemed to work, so I have reorganized my js file and now my jQuery hack works, so for anyone with similar problem, try:

```
$('[checked=checked]').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Personally I dont like this solution, feels unprofessional, but it works and I have to have radio buttons there.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is just "checked". You don't need "checked=checked".

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="targets[image][0]" value="/images/Targets/target1.png" checked>
```

Comment: Doesnt work, does the same as checked="checked" or checked="true"